# How to render a cross media bar (PS3 UI) in html/css/js

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, user-experience

I am looking to make a cross media bar in html/css/js but have no idea where to start. I consider myself capable but in this case I am out of my debt.

What I am trying to do is this:
[image]

How do I lay out my elements in html to make this easy to render in javascript.

Options:

- Tables: doesnt seem very dynamic when adding rows, or columns
- Divs: hard to dynamically render both rows and columns without a fixed number

Answer (score 0):

This kind of interface isn't very friendly to users using a desktop/laptop computers. If you still want to go ahead:

Use divs with `display: flex`.

Break the section down to two planes, the horizontal bar and a vertical bar. Your vertical bar's items are going to be positioned with `position:absolute` and javascript will ensure it doesn't intersect with the horizontal bar.

You could try with libraries like [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/).

Might be best asking a specific problem you're having or go to a chat room